# Añadir HTML en un div con un foreach Js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, foreach, xmlhttprequest

espero podais ayudarme.

Tengo un div en el que quiero mostrar una serie de registros.

```
<div id='Pacientes'>

</div>
```

Estoy haciendo una peticion `XMLHttpRequest` a mi base de datos, esta me devuelve un conjunto de registros, y lo que quiero hacer es imprimir por cada registro dentro de un div un fragmento de HTMl, el problema es que es un codigo algo largo.

```
<div class="card-patient">
    <div class="header-card">
         <div>{{ $Paciente->nombre." ".$Paciente->apellidos}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="body-card">
         <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/UsersPNG/user-icon.png') }}">
         <center>   
            <p class="span-carnet">{{ $Paciente->carnet }}</p>
         </center>
         <center>
            <button class="btn-atender" onclick="attendPatient({{ $Paciente->ID }})"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Atender</button>
            <button class="btn-ver"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verPacienteModal" onclick="showPatient({{ $Paciente->ID }})"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Ver</button>
         </center>
         <center>
             <button class="btn-ausente" onclick="absentPatient({{ $Paciente->ID }})"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Ausente</button>
                                
             <button class="btn-derivar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#derivarPacienteModal" onclick="loadModalDerive({{ $Paciente->ID }})"><i class="fas fa-laptop-medical"></i> Derivar</button>
          </center>
     </div>
   <div class="footer-card">
       <center><p>EN ESPERA</p> </center>
   </div>
</div>
```

El problema, como es un código largo no se como poder imprimirlo. Y otro problema es que como uso un foreach estaba intentando usar el INNERHtml, pero este solo me imprime uno, el ultimo, por que cada vez que va a imprimir otro, borra el anterior y lo sobrescribe.

Use anteriormente esto, para rellenar un combobox, pero no se como rellenar un Div.

```
let especialidades = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
let input = document.getElementById('Especialidades');
especialidades.forEach(especialidad => {
     i = i+1;
     input.options[i]   = new Option(especialidad.especialidad,especialidad.ID);
});
```

Necesito algo parecido para rellenar mi div.

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado la siguiente solución, no se si es la mas optima, pero funciona.

```
<div id='Pacientes'>

</div>

//Seleccionamos el Div que lo contendram y luego lo limpiamos.
let container = document.querySelector('#Pacientes');
container.innerHTML = "";
                
//Con el foreach recorreremos el JSON y luego aplicaremos el innerHTML con 
lo signos += esto es importante porque es lo que empezará a sumar campos en 
lugar de solo reemplazarlos.
 Y luego usamos la comillas de los acentos, para contener el HTML que deseamos mostrar.

Pacientes.forEach(date => {
   container.innerHTML += `Aquí puedes escribir todo tu código HTML y  las variables serian  date.nombrecampo `;
});
```

Ese seria la solución que encontré yo. Espero les sirva